# Multiple Interstitials pop up with mopub mediation in my android app

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub, millennial-media

I am trying to integrate mopub into my app. I am using millennial media and admob ad networks. I come across this weird issue, it loads interstial ad from millennial media first and then admob interstitial when it should only show either mmedia or admob interstitial and not both. It'll be a very bad experience for users to see to interstitial ads.

How do I resolve this issue.

in my activity's onCreate method, I have following code.

```
mInterstitial = new MoPubInterstitial(this, <fullscreen_phone_adunit_id>);
mInterstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(this);
mInterstitial.load();
```

and here are callback methods

```
    @Override
    public void onInterstitialClicked(MoPubInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(MoPubInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialFailed(MoPubInterstitial arg0,
            MoPubErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialLoaded(MoPubInterstitial interstitial) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (interstitial.isReady()) {
            mInterstitial.show();
        } else {
            // Other code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialShown(MoPubInterstitial arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: You have a confusing use case and are only showing a fraction of the code used. Simplify your scenario and post all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Believe in order to achieve the scenario you described where one or another ad network's inventory is shown, you may set this up within the MoPub UI over at app.mopub.com

Over there you can set up your network priorities and manage your segments.
Have a backfill order that will trigger when no other options are not met.  Within the backfill order, CPMs are used to prioritize which particular orders are filled first.

Please take a look over here for more information on different order types:
http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/780787-type-of-orders

You may find how to create and set up your order line items here:
http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/784995

Cheers,
WiLL